# Simple moving averages with formula

Tags: r

I have to calculate Simple Moving Averages on some data with this formula in R:

[image: formula]

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```r
Func <- function(xt){
  St <- 1/10*sum(sapply(0:9, function(z) xt-z))
  return(St)
}
```

And the output for two example of Xt:

```r
> Func(10)
5.5
> Func(15)
10.5
```

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return the value; it only prints it to the console. Presumably the OP will want to actually get the result

Comment: @Camille, sorry, I'm not sure to understand your comments.. should I add `St <- Func(xt)` ?

Comment: If you want a function to return a value, you need to end it with the value it should return, or explicitly call `return(St)` somewhere in the function definition. Right now, if you called `x <- Func(10)`, x would be null, and the only information you would be getting from the function would be printed to the console, which isn't often very useful

Comment: @camille, thank you for your help. I was not aware of this. I'm editing my function to provide a `return`.